# GDB not understands code

Tags: c, gdb

I have code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t foo_len (const char *s)
{
  return strlen (s);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const char *a = NULL;

  printf ("size of a = %d\n", foo_len (a));

  exit (0);
}
```

Compile it with debug symbols:

```
$ gcc example.c -g -o example
```

And run in GDB

```
 $ gdb ./example

user@ubuntu:~$ gdb ./example 
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./example...done.
```

GDB run

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: ./example
```

I was expected to get something like

```
 Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
 0x0000000000400527 in foo_len (s=0x0) at example.c:8
 8    return strlen (s);
```

But got :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
106 ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S: No such file or directory.
```

Where is problem?

[Sample in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger) is not correct ?

Comment: Read the error message. The crash happens in strlen, but you have no source file of strlen (so it can´t show you the code)

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you're passing `NULL` to `strlen()`, which causes undefined behavior, and thus a crash. You seem to be expecting the undefined behavior to happen in your code, *before* the call, which makes no sense.

If you had the source code for the standard library you would be able to see the source line where it happened; it looks like your `strlen()` was written in assembly. You can of course view the instructions anyway, by asking gdb to disassemble the code using the `disassemble` command.

Also this:

```
 printf ("size of a = %d\n", foo_len (a));
```

is wrong, you can't legally print a `size_t` as if it's an `int`; it's not. You should use `%zu` to print values of type `size_t`:

```
 printf("length of a = %zu\n", foo_len(a));
```

Also, talking about the "size" of a string (and not its length) is a bit confusing.

Comment: The question is not about why there's a segfault!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I do believe that's not all I said, either.

Comment: I thought I read your answer, and then it was but a single sentence; I don't know how that could have happened, and I apologize. I'll add the original `printf` line to have an edit, so I can undo my vote. Again, my apologies.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I happened because I edited, adding lots more information to try to clarify what I meant. :)

Comment: the strange thing is that I wasn't able to take back my downvote because "I had already voted and can only change my vote after the answer has been edited", which I trusted. Strange.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Alright, that's weird but perhaps some kind of race.

Comment: So, sample in wikipedia is not correct ?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger

Comment: @vico The example *says* that it can happen elsewhere depending on how `strlen()` was implemented. How did you miss that?

Answer (score 2):

Your error happens inside `strlen`. To see the full call stack in gdb use the command `bt` for backtrace.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the segmentation fault *does* happen in strlen and not in your function, so the fact that you see it happen there is correct.

Use your distributions install tool to get the debug symbols for your C library (glibc, if in doubt), and try again.